# SQL Loop Through Columns and Insert Results into Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of Car IDs in a temp #CarIDs

```
CREATE TABLE #CarIDs(
[CARID] [nvarchar] (60) NULL,
[Type] [nvarchar] (20) NULL,
[Flag] [nvarchar] (30) NULL) GO

INSERT INTO #CarIDs (CARID, Type, Flag) VALUES ('1111','',''), ('2222','',''), ('3333','',''), ('4444','',''), ('5555','',''), ('6666','','')
```

Which gives me `SELECT * FROM #CarIDs`

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| CARID | Type  |  Flag  |
+-------+-------+--------+
|  1111 |       |        |
|  2222 |       |        |      
|  3333 |       |        |
|  4444 |       |        |
|  5555 |       |        |
|  6666 |       |        |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

How do I loop through the below table (CarHierarchy) to find out what model type is each CARID then insert into the temp table?

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Jeep  |Holden | Ford  |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 1111  |2222   | 3333  | 
| 4444  |6666   | 5555  |        
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I expect the results to be #CarIDs:

```
+-------+-------+
| CARID | Type  | 
+-------+-------+
|  1111 |Jeep   |  
|  2222 |Holden |    
|  3333 |Ford   |     
|  4444 |Jeep   |    
|  5555 |Ford   |    
|  6666 |Holden |     
+------+--------+
```

Comment: `CarHierarchy` seems like a deeply misguided design for a table. Data in a single row ought to be facts that are related to each other. *data* shouldn't be embedded in *metadata* as column names. What happens when there aren't equal numbers of each type of car?

Comment: plus 1 for sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `UNPIVOT` first the `#CarHierarchy` table and then do a `JOIN` on the `#CarIDs` table to get the correct type:

```
-- Unpivot the #CarHierarchy table using CROSS APPLY
WITH CteCarHierarchy AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM #CarHierarchy
    CROSS APPLY( VALUES
        (Jeep, 'Jeep'),
        (Holden, 'Holden'),
        (Ford, 'Ford')
    )t (CARID, Type)
)
SELECT
    ci.CARID,
    Type = cch.Type,
    ci.Flag
FROM #CarIDs ci
INNER JOIN CteCarHierarchy cch
    ON cch.CARID = ci.CARID
```

---

The `UPDATE` statement:

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500288)</kbd>

```
WITH CteCarHierarchy AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM #CarHierarchy
    CROSS APPLY( VALUES
        (Jeep, 'Jeep'),
        (Holden, 'Holden'),
        (Ford, 'Ford')
    )t (CARID, Type)
)
UPDATE ci
    SET ci.Type = cch.Type
FROM #CarIDs ci
INNER JOIN CteCarHierarchy cch
    ON cch.CARID = ci.CARID
```

Reference:

- [An Alternative (Better?) Method to UNPIVOT (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/) by Dwain Camps